# при запуске Appium выдаёт ошибку The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME

Tags: python, appium

JAVA_HOME я настраивал, но всё равно выдаёт эту ошибку. Подскажите в чём может быт проблема

Python код:

from appium import webdriver

desired_capabilities = {
"platformName": "Android",
"platformVersion": "12",
"deviceName": "Android Emulator",
"app": "C:\python_projects\TelegtamAcc\pp_binaries\org.wikipedia_2.7.50422-r-2022-10-24_50422.apk"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

при запуске кода сервер Appium так же выдаёт это:

[UiAutomator2] Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without session id

Настройки переменной среды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так написано же в чем проблема. Неправильно настраивал, значит....

Comment: Настройка, вроде верная, я прикрепил скриншот

Answer (score 0):

Я просто вставил папки которые appium просил в \Contents\Home\     appium требовал папки bin и lib. Главное после этого перезапустить appium